# How to prevent line break in a long line on the title page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, titles

I am trying to design a very simple title page for my thesis. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\scshape
\large{\noindent Der} \\[0.5ex]
\LARGE{Satz von Bézout} \\[0.5ex]
\large{und das} \\[0.5ex]
\LARGE{\mbox{Gruppengesetz auf elliptischen Kurven}} \\[3ex]

\normalfont
\large{------ Bachelor-Arbeit ------}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

My problem is, that I really would like the phrase »Gruppengesetz auf elliptischen Kurven« to appear in a single line without a line break. So I used an `\mbox`. But this causes the line not to be correctly centred with respect to the other lines, probably because it produces an overfull box. What can I do? I'd be grateful for any help, since I am rather a LaTeX novice. Could be also a solution using TikZ.

Comment: Note that `\large` and alike commands *don't* take an argument, but are declarations like `\scshape`; just omit the braces: ``\large und das \\``. Also `\noindent` is unnecessary when `\centering` is in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution consists in using `\makebox[0pt]` (or `\clap`, from the `mathtools` package). In the following code, I intentionally increased the horizontal margins to make the result more evident:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, hmargin = 35mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\scshape
\large{\noindent Der} \\[0.5ex]
\LARGE{Satz von Bézout} \\[0.5ex]
\large{und das} \\[0.5ex]
\LARGE{\makebox[0pt]{Gruppengesetz auf elliptischen Kurven}} \\[3ex]

\normalfont
\large{------ Bachelor-Arbeit ------}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `\hspace*{-"length"}` at the beginning of the `\mbox{}`.

Comment: Thanks. This might work since LaTeX luckily specifies the exact excess of the overfull box in its error log. But I still have a little doubt that my code really is a good solution at all for this situation. So I am still curious whether somebody comes up with a totally different idea. But if not, then I will do it this way. Thanks!